# svn_export in PHP - "Path is not a working copy directory"

Tags: php, svn, pecl

I'm trying to build a project deployment tool, and part of it needs to export a repo from a working copy within PHP.

My directory structure is like

```
/
- dir1
  -  dir2
     -  versioned
```

and I want to export the 'versioned' directory. So I have

```
svn_export('/dir1/dir2/versioned', 'source');
```

but for some reason, I get this error:

```
 svn_export(): svn error(s) occured 155007 (Path is not a working copy directory) '/dir1/dir2' is not a working copy 2 (No such file or directory) Can't open file '/dir1/dir2/.svn/entries': No such file or directory
```

So for some reason this is speaking about 'dir2', not 'versioned'. Is there a reason for this? Is there something about this implementation I'm not getting?

Thanks!

Comment: @Lowgain: In the [manual](http://php.net/svn_export), they use trailing slashes in the *$frompath*, but you're not. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Why not use [`Phing`](http://phing.info)?  It has the tasks to handle all of this for you...

Comment: Hm. Have you tried adding a trailing slash: `/dir1/dir2/versioned/`?

Comment: @netcoder - just tried it with the slash, unfortunately no change.

Comment: @ircmaxwell - thanks for showing me that, it looks interesting! our specific deployment tool has other features that aren't a part of phing, but I am going to see if I can do any sort of integration into what we've created

Comment: @Lowgain: You can add your own plugins to it.  It's nice, because it's just command line targets: `phing test`, `phing build`, `phing document`, `phing deploy`, etc...  And you can set dependencies that say you can't deploy unless you've built, and you can't build unless you've tested, etc...  Great stuff...

Comment: @ircmaxwell are there any APIs to integrate it into a web application or would I need to use exec() and such?

Comment: @Lowgain: Phing is built in PHP, so you can use [its API how you please](http://phing.info/docs/api/trunk/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I overlooked like 3 times that I was using a repo that didn't exist anymore

Answer (score 0):

Where is the root of the repository?  You need to make it a relative path -- as your code stands, it looks in the root directory for /dir1 (root of the server, not the html root)